# Como funcionam os números em hexadecimal?

Tags: hexadecimal, representação-numérica

Eu tenho visto que bibliotecas de software escritas em C, no geral, costumam usar números hexadecimais. E programadores Assembly também precisam ser ninjas com este sistema numérico.

Não é em qualquer lugar que se acha um programador que saiba ler hexadecimal decentemente e muito menos fazer uso dos números. Mas hexadecimais são bastante comuns, principalmente em programação de sistemas, programação de baixo nível e segurança da informação:

- Payloads de exploits precisam dos opcodes em hexadecimal
- HexDumps, o nome já diz tudo.
- Eu não sei porquê, mas hexadecimais também estão bastante presente em macros de C.

Considerando a importância desse sistema, eu pergunto: como funcionam os números em hexadecimal?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

### Números são simplesmente números

Pode parecer estranho, mas não há muito o que se aprender em hexadecimal que seja diferente da matemática que você já conhece.

A matemática dos binários, decimais, hexadecimais (que é o mesmo que "base 16"), base 32, base 36, base 64, assim como de qualquer outra base, é a mesma. O que muda é a quantidade de símbolos para **representar** os algarismos.

**"Por acaso"**, como nossos dígitos arábicos comuns vão apenas de 0 a 9, escolheu-se acrescentar as letras de A a F para se representar os algarismos extras, visto que hexadecimal é uma notação com 16 dígitos, em vez dos 10 que estamos acostumados.

Em vez de se criar uma nova coleção de desenhos para representar os números após o 9, usou-se o que já havia pronto, por conveniência - as letras - mas dando um novo sentido a elas.

- Em decimal, usamos os dígitos arábicos `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`;
- em hexadecimal, usamos os dígitos `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F` <sup><sup>1</sup></sup>;
- em base 36 vamos mais longe ainda, de `0` até a letra `Z`!
- em binário, vai só de `0` a `1`, mas a lógica ainda é a mesma.

Assim como o último número do decimal, que é 9, somado a 1 vira 10 (ou seja, volta pro zero e ganha uma nova "casa" ao lado), se pegarmos o último "número" do Hexa, que é "F" e adicionarmos "1", o resultado é 10 em hexadecimal. Da mesma forma, no binário (que é composto por 2 dígitos, "0" e "1" respectivamente), somando 1 + 1 temos 10 em binário.

```
DECIMAL         HEXADECIMAL       BASE36
9 + 1 = 10      F + 1 = 10        Z + 1 = 10
```

Resumo: a matemática é a mesma.

<sub>1. Antes do hexadecimal, havia um sistema "sexadecimal" cujos algarismos eram respectivamente `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 K S N J F L`.  Ambos funcionam exatamente da mesma forma, apesar de as letras escolhidas para a representação do 10º ao 15º algarismos serem diferentes.</sub>

### Na informática

O Hexadecimal é muito presente na informática pela facilidade que tem de representar os números de uma outra base: o binário.

Como tanto o hexadecimal quanto o binário são números em potência de dois, você consegue conciliar alguns conceitos de ambas as bases de forma interessante. Para isto, vamos partir desta tabelinha:

```
Decimal Hexa Binário
      0    0       0
      1    1       1
      2    2      10
      3    3      11
      4    4     100
      5    5     101
      6    6     110
      7    7     111
      8    8    1000
      9    9    1001
     10    A    1010
     11    B    1011
     12    C    1100
     13    D    1101
     14    E    1110 
     15    F    1111 <-- Atenção a este caso!
     16   10   10000
     17   11   10001
     18   12   10010
     19   13   10011
     ...
```

Note que ao chegar no 15 decimal, tanto o hexadecimal quanto o binário chegaram na última casa antes de "virar" mais uma casa. Como essa "virada" coincide, o hexadecimal se tornou uma maneira muito prática de representar números binários.

Para cada um dos binários de 4 dígitos (0000 a 1111), temos exatamente um algarismo do hexadecimal. Sabendo ou entendendo como contar estes 16 dígitos, convertemos qualquer hexadecimal para binário e vice-versa.

Assim, olhando a tabela acima, fica fácil converter um número binário:

```
   111010110110110  -> original em binário
111 0101 1011 0110  -> dividido em grupos de nibbles
  7    5    B    6  -> substituído pelos números da tabela.
              75B6  -> reescrito em hexadecimal
```

**Onde o hexadecimal entra nessa história então?**

O binário é a base da tecnologia corrente, pois tanto nos HDs quanto na memória, ou nos processadores, a informação é representada como "ligado" ou "desligado" apenas (os famigerados *bits*).

Isto não se aplica a processadores quânticos, mas espere mais um pouco pra ter um desses na sua mesa.

Já faz algum tempo que os processadores e memória em geral utilizam-se de espaços para armazenar informação organizados em pacotes de 4 bits (chamado de *nibble*), 8 bits (*byte*), 16 bits (*word*), 32 bits (*dword*), e assim por diante.

- Para representar um nibble (0000 a 1111), basta exatamente um algarismo hexadecimal (0 a F);
- para representar um byte, bastam dois deles, de 00 a FF;
- e assim seguimos, para as "medidas" como 0000 a FFFF, e maiores.

Exemplos "Visuais":

- É muito mais fácil escrever 5F do que 01011111, não?
- Um *MAC Address* de placa de rede: 00-5F-FF-E0-AA-FF em vez de 0-95-255-224-170-255
- Cor #FF00CC em vez de rgb(255,0,204);
  talvez nesse caso o hexadecimal cause estranheza inicialmente, mas como as cores para a paleta web 216 são múltiplas de 51 decimal (que é o mesmo que 33 hexadecimal), temos os algarismos mais comuns sendo 00, 33, 66, 99, cc e ff, que são abreviados para um dígito cada (#33cc00 é o mesmo que #3c0 para os browsers).
- Um hexdump ficaria muito confuso se representássemos os bytes de 0 a 255 em vez de 00 a FF

Exemplo de hexdump:

```
00000000  255044462D312E34 0A312030206F626A  %PDF-1.4.1 0 obj
00000010  0A3C3C0A2F426173 65466F6E74202F48  .<<./BaseFont /H
00000020  656C766574696361 0A2F456E636F6469  elvetica./Encodi
00000030  6E67202F57696E41 6E7369456E636F64  ng /WinAnsiEncod
...
```

Imagine se tivéssemos que usar 3 casas, ou separadores para identificar os números.

Assim, convencionou-se a usar hexadecimal para muitas coisas em que facilita a leitura e o contexto da informação.

### Como "ler" o hexadecimal?

R: Sem medo :)

Da mesma forma que em decimal cada "casa" é multiplicada por potências de dez:

```
279  =  ( 2 * 10 * 10 ) + ( 7 * 10 ) + ( 9 )
```

Em hexadecimal basta multiplicar por potências de 16:

```
3AF     =     ( 3 * 16 * 16 ) + (  A * 16 ) + (  F )
é o mesmo que ( 3 * 16 * 16 ) + ( 10 * 16 ) + ( 15 ) em decimal.
```

Parece complexo à primeira vista, mas depois que você acostuma com os valores de A a F, o resto vira hábito (da mesma forma que acostumamos com o exemplo de 0 a 9 no dia-a-dia).

Apenas para completar o raciocínio, veja um outro exemplo, desta vez em binário:

```
1101 = ( 1 * 2 * 2 * 2 ) + ( 1 * 2 * 2 ) + ( 0 * 2 ) + ( 1 )
```

Guardadas as devidas proporções, é como aquela cena do Cypher em Matrix: "*I don't even see the code. All I see now is blonde, brunette, redhead.*" <sup><sup>2</sup></sup>

<sub><sup>2. "Eu nem vejo mais o código. Agora eu simplesmente vejo loira, morena, ruiva."</sup></sub>

Comment: Muito esclarecedor! Nem sabia disso que a notação hexadecimal facilitava e tornava mais legível a notação binária! Agora parece tão óbvio: 10 = 111111110000000. E, eu não entendi a sua referência a cena. Eu assistir Matrix, mas não me lembro que cena é essa. Por acaso a fala em sí se refere a mulheres?

Comment: @Sid o Cypher está olhando o monitor, com aqueles símbolos verdes, e o Neo pergunta "Você vê sempre codificado?" e aí o Cypher responde (resumidamente): "A matrix é muito complexa pra se decodificar em tempo real, mas depois você acostuma. Eu nem vejo mais o código, já vejo loira, morena, ruiva..."

Comment: A propósito, `240 dec = F0 hex = 11110000 bin` e `10 dec = 0A hex = 00001010 bin`. `1111111100000000 = FF00`, ou seja, `65280` em decimal. Separe pra ler: `1111 1111 0000 0000 = F F 0 0`, ou seja `(15 * 16 * 16 * 16 ) + ( 15 * 16 * 16 ) + ( 0 * 16 ) + ( 0 ) = 65280`

Comment: bacco excelente resposta, lembraste quase os casos todos! +1

Comment: I don't even see the code. All I see is 0xB00B5

Comment: Simplesmente fantástica essa explicação

Comment: Talvez valesse a pena lembrar que, em arquiteturas mais antigas (como o PDP-10 onde o C foi criado), a unidade "natural" era um grupo de 36 bits, e por isso nessas arquiteturas era muito comum o uso de base _octal_ 0–7, já que uma palavra de PDP-10 é formada por seis grupos de dois dígitos octais — daí o uso de octais em permissões Unix e o suporte a essa base em C.

Comment: @Wtrmute é uma boa observação. Nao sei se a questão do PDP-10 teria muito a ver com a pergunta original a ponto de entrar em detalhes, mas de qq forma, quando for mexer de novo na resposta com mais calma, acho que compensa no minimo por exemplos em octal também, até pq é uma base que confunde o pessoal.

Comment: Ótima explicação. Gosto de pensar que o decimal é uma caixa ontem cabem 10 itens e para acrescentar mais itens seria necessário outra caixa. Já o Hexadecimal é uma caixa onde cabem 16 itens e binário apenas dois.

Answer (score 5):

Um bom uso que se tem do hexadecimal se tratando de programação é para a criação de *flags*, como por exemplo com a API do Windows, quando se vai mostrar um *message box* e se quer que ela seja do tipo Sim/Não e que seja mostrado o ícone de interrogação você vai passar como parâmetro para a função as flags `MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION`.

Estas constantes possuem os valores `0x4` e `0x20` respectivamente, as quais em binário seriam correspondentes a `100` e `100000`, assim quando se faz o OR deste valores você combina os bits de um jeito que é fácil verificar quais foram as `flags` usadas.

Mas isso pode ser feito com números decimais da mesma forma, afinal são basicamente os números `4` e `32`, a vantagem de se usar o hexadecimal está mesmo na hora de se criar estas constantes.

Para se criar as constantes cada uma usando um bit diferente basicamente você começa do 1 e vai dobrando os valores, bem simples, uma conta muito fácil de se fazer de cabeça com números pequenos, porém em hexadecimal você não precisa fazer conta alguma, só precisa decorar a sequencia das quatro primeiras *flags*, segue uma tabela comparando os valores, hexadecimal, decimal e binário:

```
0x01 =   1 = 00000001
0x02 =   2 = 00000010
0x04 =   4 = 00000100
0x08 =   8 = 00001000
0x10 =  16 = 00010000
0x20 =  32 = 00100000
0x40 =  64 = 01000000
0x80 = 128 = 10000000
```

E ele sempre vai seguir este mesmo padrão, adicionando um zero a mais a cada 4 valores, o próximo valor hexadecimal seria `0x100`, e se torna realmente útil quando se tem muitas flags, por exemplo se você está na flag `0x4000` não precisa fazer calculo algum para saber que a próxima é a `0x8000`, se usasse decimal você estaria na flag `16384` e já não é tão simples dobrar o valor dela de cabeça, se não prestar atenção pode até errar o valor.