# Usando hexadecimais como ID no banco de dados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, chave-primária

Pela barra de navegação, percebemos que o Google utiliza valores hexadecimais para identificar registros:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O *print* acima foi retirado do GMail, mas o mesmo ocorre para outros serviços como o Google Drive.

- Qual a vantagem de se utilizar valores hexadecimais ao invés de inteiros?
- Que tipo de coluna é apropriado nesse caso: *string* (*varchar*), binário, outro?

Comment: Só uma observação, o Google não usa banco de dados relacional e sim o BigTable, banco de dados orientado a coluna http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable

Comment: Veja também no SOpt: [Como funcionam os números em hexadecimal?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13573/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Qual a vantagem de se utilizar valores hexadecimais ao invés de
>   inteiros?

Hexadecimal é uma representação ligeiramente mais curta. Por exemplo, os dois valores a seguir são idênticos:

```
999999999 DEX
3B9AC9FF  HEX
```

Você também tem uma melhor visão da distribuição dos bits, já que cada posição em hexadecimal equivale a 4 bits:

```
   3    B    9    A    C    9    F    F   HEX
0011 1011 1001 1010 1100 1001 1111 1111   BIN
```

> Que tipo de coluna é apropriado nesse caso: string (varchar), binário,
>   outro

Usualmente numérico, mas pode ser binário. Hexa é apenas uma representação; é o caso do tipo GUID, que o SQL Server armazena como um `varbinary(16)`.

Para um exemplo deste tipo de conversão, veja essa resposta no Stack Overflow (inglês): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078209/sql-server-2008-convert-from-guid-to-bigint-and-back

Comment: Eu queria poder dar mais de um voto positivo a essa resposta.

Comment: Então, basicamente, o Google converte de inteiro para hexa para montar a URL e depois de hexa para inteiro para buscar o registro no banco?

Comment: @Andrey Pense da seguinte maneira: Um inteiro é apenas um conjunto de bytes até que alguém precise de uma visualização, que pode ser decimal, hexadeximal ou qualquer outra (base 2, base 36, etc.) A representação hexadecimal é mais próxima (e menos custosa [citation needed]) do formato binário nativo do que a decimal. Nesse sentido, você está plenamente correto - o formato hexa é uma escolha para disponibilização em uma URL limitada a caracteres ASCII, por exemplo.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado. =)