# Possível SHA256 retornar 128bytes após fazer assinatura?

Tags: .net, vb.net, criptografia, sha-256

Estou usando o seguinte código para pegar meu certificado e assinar meus CNPJs,
porém estou usando o algorítimo SHA256, mas ele está retornando 128bytes.
Alguém sabe dizer o que está errado? 
Segue o Código:

```
  Dim data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Me.txtCNPJSoftwareHouse.Text + Me.txtCNPJEmpresa.Text)
  Dim csp As RSACryptoServiceProvider = DirectCast(cert.PrivateKey, RSACryptoServiceProvider)


            ' cert = certificado X509
            Dim sha As New SHA256Managed()
            Dim hash As Byte() = sha.ComputeHash(data)
            Dim encrypted As Byte() = csp.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"))



            Me.txtBox.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted)
```

A variavel data fica com 28 bytes

A variavel hash fica com 32 bytes

A variavel encrypted fica com 128 bytes < - PROBLEMA

No final meu txtBox.text recebe apenas 172Bytes e deveria receber 344bytes se a variavel "encrypted" estivesse recebendo os 256bytes

Comment: E por que você acha que SHA256 vai ter 256 bytes? Ele tem 256 bits. pra falar a verdade estou tentando entender como ficou tão brande. Até existe a necessidade de 64 bytes para representar de forma hexadecimal, mas não 128. Será que está gastando 2 bytes por ser UTF-16? São *bytes* ou caracteres? Vou pesquisar. http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator

Comment: Entendi.
Vc teria alguma solução para esse caso o que posso estar fazendo para que eu chegue a esse resultado final de 344 caracteres? 
obrigado.

Comment: Depende do que você quer fazer. Por que precisa chegar neste tamanho?

Comment: Pq isso seria uma chave de vinculo entre meu sistema e o S@T-Fiscal da Receita Federal, eles explicam que a chave assinada com meu ICP-Brasil(Certificado Digital) + a concatenação dos CNPJs (AC + Contribuinte) deve ser no total de 344Chars com Base64

Comment: Será que não está faltando alguma coisa? Não parece ser problema do SHA. Ou você tem alguma informação que demonstre que é?

Comment: Aqui nesse PDF disponibilizado pela Receita:http://www.fazenda.sp.gov.br/sat/downloads/Especificacao_SAT_v_ER_2_11_4.pdf
No paragrafo 2.1.3 Pag. 15 ele explica.

Comment: encrypted não é um SHA256... E sim um RSA usando o SHA... SHA é um mecanismo de Hashing... RSA de criptografia.

Comment: Daniloloko, entendi e qual seria a solução para isso?
Obrigado

Comment: O certificado é um arquivo .pfx correto ou uma chave? irei fazer um exemplo em c#

Comment: Então Danilo, é um cartão A3, com 1 Chave privada e outra publica, e sim quando exportado ele pode ser um arquivo .pfx
Porém estou com a função de localizar o Certificado Conectado em meu micro, no caso a função busca a CHAVE PRIVADA!
Pode fazer, depois eu passo para o Vb,rs
OBRIGADO!

Comment: @FelipeWalleg Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irei apenas iniciar uma discussão doque pode estar acontecendo...

```
 Dim data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Me.txtCNPJSoftwareHouse.Text + Me.txtCNPJEmpresa.Text)
 Dim csp As RSACryptoServiceProvider = DirectCast(cert.PrivateKey, RSACryptoServiceProvider)

 //vou continuar o exemplo em c#(não entendo muito vb.net)

 byte[] signature = csp.SignData(data, "SHA256");
 bool isValid = csp.VerifyData(data, "SHA256", signature);//verifica se e valido

//Conversao para UTF8 caso for necessario ser lido...
string final = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(signature);
```

[Um link que pode te ajudar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444586/how-can-i-sign-a-file-using-rsa-and-sha256-with-net#comment37081635_7475985)

Voce pode utilizar o CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256") ao inves de "SHA256", porem nao sei qual diferença irá causar.

Comment: Opááá!
Vou passar para o VB aqui!!
Então eu uso o CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256")
Porem ele está trazendo os 32 Chars, mas no caso se pegarmos esses 32(byte) * 8(bit), chego no resultado final.
Mas vou converter aqui para VB.net!
Obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Apenas utilizei a convenção que esta no link na resposta... nao sei se ira funcionar pois a conversao da receita pode ter alguma particularidade... Porem nada que tentando iremos descobrir :D

Comment: rsrs
Então, Danilo.
Seria engraçado se não fosse trágico,rs
Fiz a conversão do código consegui chegar na mesma chave criptografada que eu conseguia antes.
E deu a mesma coisa!
byte[] signature = csp.SignData(data, "SHA256"); = 128Chars =[

Comment: isValid retorno true... tente debugar e ver se os dados estao certos realmente... string final = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(signature);

Comment: Então, está retornando TRUE, estou começando a achar que o problema é meu certificado A3, pq vi alguns usuários falando sobre essa chave feita no A1 e conseguiram o resultado final de 344chars

Comment: A assinatura signAC nao precisa ser exatamente 344 caracteres, é de 1 a 344... o assinaturaQRCOD sim! (pag 55)
Esse tamanho é refencial a key que foi passada para o RSA... o tamanho final sempre é baseado na KEY (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658728/rsa-signature-size). Ou seja... testa que ta certo!

Comment: Então, 172chars que está sendo a gerado está correto ?
Mas mesmo assim acho estrango os 256 gerar apenas os 128chars.
Mas blz, Obrigado mesmo por enquanto, Danilo!!

Answer (score 2):

O SHA-256 tem 256 *bits* e não 256 *bytes*. Estou tentando entender como ficou tão grande.

256 *bits* são 32 *bytes*. Até existe a necessidade de 64 *bytes*, ou mais precisamente 64 caracteres, afinal cada *byte* precisará de dois dígitos para [representar em hexadecimal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13573/101).

Não faço ideia de onde está saindo os 128 bytes. Só se for um problema de *encoding* e está usando UTF-16 que é o padrão de *string* para o .NET e que ocupa 2 *bytes* por caractere.

Comment: Entendi, mas convenhamos que assim que ele passasse por aqui " Dim hash As Byte() = sha.ComputeHash(data)" Ele deveria gerar os 256 e não 128.
Aqui ele só disponibiliza UTF-7 / UTF-8 e UTF-32

Comment: mas será que no `Me.txtBox.Text` não está convertendo para UTF-16? Só uma suposição, sem ver não dá para dar muita certeza.

Comment: Olha eu não tinha pensado nisso, e realmente faz sentindo.
Vou verificar...
Quer que eu poste algo para te ajudar?
É que já estou a tempos quebrando a cabeça com esse código e finalmente estou perto de terminar,rs