# O que são números de notação Decimal, Hexadecimal e Octal?

Tags: hexadecimal, decimal, representação-numérica, octal

O que são números de notação Decimal (base 10), Hexadecimal  (base 16) e Octal (base 8)? No livro o código está dessa maneira:

```
<?php    

    // numero decimal
    $a = 1234;

    // numero octal (equivalente a 83 em decimal)
    $a = 0123;

    // numero hexadecimal (equivalente a 26 em decimal)
    $a = 0x1A;

?>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Isto é conhecido como [notação posicional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation). É a forma como representamos números.

## Decimal

A [representação decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal) todo mundo conhece, vai de 0 à 9 e até onde sei é assim por causa do número de dedos que o humano tem. É a forma como os humanos crescem acostumados. Cada posição à esquerda adiciona o total de unidades do sistema representacional, ou seja, no decimal cada casa extra à esquerda vale o número representado vezes 10.

## Hexadecimal

A [representação hexadecimal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13573/101) vai de 0 à 15. Isto está mais próximo de como o computador funciona. Como tudo no computador é binário, tudo vai escalando com base 2, números que programadores consideram "redondos" são 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 e mais que isto precisaria de mais que um *byte* para representar. Fica mais fácil e mais linear representar esses números com base 16, ir de 0 à F (A = 10, B = 11, C = 12, D = 13, E = 14, F = 15). Então `1A` é o mesmo que 26 em decimal já que 1 neste caso é ele vezes 16 (o total de número que podem ser representados em hexa mais 10 que é o valor de A.

Note que para diferenciar do decimal o literal do hexadecimal, na maioria das linguagens, deve começar com `0x`.

Cores são um exemplo para quem desenvolve para *web* de uso do hexadecimal. A cor `FFFFFF` é o branco absoluto. O primeiro `FF` diz que é o vermelho máximo, ou 255. Depois o `FF` seguinte indica o verde máximo e o último `FF` indica o azul máximo. Quando todas as cores em toda sua plenitude são combinada, temos o branco. Para representar a mesma coisa de forma decimal teria que ser `255, 255, 255`. A vírgula é necessária porque é comum o decimal poder ter um número variável de dígitos e no hexadecimal é comum usarmos um número fixo de dígitos, no caso 2, já que com 2 dígitos podemos representar todos os números possíveis em um *byte*.

## Octal

Octal era usado em computadores com uma arquitetura específica, hoje tem pouca relevância. Ainda pode ser usado para representar situações onde a base deve ser 8 (de 0 à 7), mas é raro ter uso efetivo. Portanto para representar o decimal 8 em octal ficaria 10. Note que ele segue o modelo do hexadecimal usando uma proporção baseada no binário. Algumas linguagens não dão mais suporte a esta representação. Normalmente usa-se um zero inicial para indicar que a representação é octal. Isto pode gerar *bugs* em alguns casos e o programador não tomar cuidado.

## Binário

Além disto algumas linguagens usam a representação binária que é a mais básica para computadores. Esta é simples já que tem só dois dígitos possíveis, 0 e 1. Como a base é 2, cada dígito extra à esquerda é elevado à 2. Com 8 dígitos temos um *byte*, os mesmos 256 valores diferentes quando usamos 2 dígitos em hexadecimal. Esta é uma representação útil em casos limitados mas pode ser interessante quando o dado é composto por informação booleana de alguma forma, quando precisa mostrar estados de ligado e desligado.

## Conversão

De uma maneira geral para converter de uma base menor para uma maior é feito multiplicação de cada dígito da direita para a esquerda do número que deseja converter pelo número resultante da potência da base por uma sequência de números começando em 0 (lembrando que todo número elevado a 0 resulta em 1).

Para fazer a operação contrária vai fazendo divisões sucessivas usando a base como divisor e pegando o resto de cada divisão. O primeiro resto vai à direita e os demais vão sendo colocados à sua esquerda.

[image: Divisões sucessivas para achar o binário]

Isto é uma simplificação da conversão. Não dá para usar em qualquer situação.

## Mais próximo do padrão do computador

Para os computadores, 10 é um número estranho, é uma representação usada para facilitar a vida de um bicho estranho, ao mesmo tempo pode criar algumas dificuldades.

Quase todas as linguagens, de *assembly* à JavaScript, possuem pelo menos o decimal e hexadecimal e eles devem ser usados quando são mais convenientes em cada caso. Em PHP é mais raro o uso do hexadecimal na maioria dos casos.

Note que todos esses números representam um mesmo número de forma diferente. Para computadores o número é representado da mesma forma, em última análise através de elétrons circulando. A representação no código da linguagem é algo que importa apenas para os humanos enxergarem melhor o que estão fazendo, é mais uma abstração.

## Representação textual

O que você vê de número na tela é uma representação textual do número e não o número em si. Assim como no papel, você tem uma representação textual, não é um número. Eu sei que pode ser difícil entender isso porque você se acostumou sempre entender que o que está vendo ali no papel é o número, mas o número existe na natureza, e existem representações diversas dele, você ver  uma par de pedras pode representar o número 2. Ter elétrons em certa organização pode representar números, o que você vê é apenas um texto que representa um número.

Por isso quando alguém fala para converter um número de uma notação para outra geralmente ela está falando de converter uma representação textual para outra.

Na verdade muitas vezes nem isso é feito, está apenas pegando um número e gerando uma determinada representação textual. Um dos motivos que isto ocorre é que é normal sempre ter na linguagem uma forma de imprimir o texto de números de forma natural, de forma que as pessoas nem percebem que tem uma conversão ali. É comum ter como imprimir em outras notações, e não precisaria fazer algoritmo algum, mas professores e autores costumam colocar isso como exercício para fazer manualmente. Eles ajudam amplificar o mito de que números são decimais porque eles não mandam você converter para a notação decimal (é o que falo sempre, as pessoas repetem o que viram outras fazendo, elas não entendem o que está fazendo).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Acho que ficava bem um exemplo de conversão entre eles e se calhar um aparte com o sistema binário também ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. logo você vem para eu falar de binário, ficaria *off-topic* :P Sabe que eu pensei em colocar e não coloquei porque lembrei de você ontem :) Mas eu vou melhorar sim.

Comment: Ahahah Sim mas uma coisa é divagar no assunto, outra é complementar a resposta. ;)

Answer (score 8):

Números sempre representam uma quantidade, porém existem várias maneiras de se representar os números. A mais comum é o sistema decimal, que usa 10 dígitos (de `0` a `9`). E o que fazemos no sistema decimal para expressar números que não podem ser representados com um só dígito? Acrescentamos um segundo dígito. Veja:

```
              10       
 uma dezena --^^-- zero unidades
       10      +    0     =>    10
```

```
              13       
 uma dezena --^^-- três unidades
       10      +    3     =>    13
```

O sistema decimal usa a **base 10**, ou seja, com 10 unidades precisamos de uma casa a mais à esquerda (a casa das dezenas) para representar o número. Da mesma maneira, a cada 10 dezenas precisamos de ainda outra casa, a das centenas:

```
               115       
 uma centena --^^^-- cinco unidades
                |--- uma dezena
       100   + 10   +   5     =>    115
```

Porém a base 10 não é a única maneira de se representar os números. Pode-se usar qualquer base. O sistema binário usa a base 2, que só tem dois dígitos, `0` e `1`. Portanto, em binário:

```
0   =>   0
1   =>   1
10  =>   2  (1 * 2 + 0)
11  =>   3  (1 * 2 + 1)
100 =>   4  (1 * 4 + 0 + 0)
...
```

O sistema **octal** usa a base 8, que só tem os dígitos de `0` a `7`. Portanto, em octal:

```
...
6   =>   6
7   =>   7
10  =>   8
11  =>   9  (1 * 8 + 1)
12  =>   10 (1 * 8 + 2)
...
20  =>   16 (2 * 8 + 0)
...
100 =>   64 (1 * 64 + 0 + 0)
```

O sistema hexadecimal usa dezesseis dígitos: os dígitos `0` a `9` mais as letras `A` até `F`. Assim:

```
 9  =>   9
 A  =>   10
 B  =>   11
 C  =>   12
 D  =>   13
 E  =>   14
 F  =>   15
10  =>   16  (1 * 16 + 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

João.... isso tem mais haver com arquitetura de computadores do que com `PHP` propriamente dito, como o nome mesmo já diz, são números de base X, convertidos para uma outra base.

Pra elucidar melhor a resposta:

[image: Um exemplo de tabela de conversão de base de números]

São muito uteis em linguagens de baixo nível... como `C`, `Cobol`, `Fortran`, `Assembly` por exemplo.

Comment: mandar procurar no Google não é resposta. Aqui é um site de Q&A, damos respostas que realmente respondem a pergunta, não ficamos conversando com os usuários. Fora que há imprecisões na pouca informação fornecida.

Comment: @bigow respeito sua opnião, mas não mandei ele procurar, aconselhei uma pesquisa mais aprofundada, antes de fazer perguntas que o mínimo de esforço de busca, já poderiam solucionar...
A pergunta basicamente foi, o que são números na base `Hexa`, `Octal`, `Decimal`, e ao meu ver, essa pergunta já é uma resposta da mesma.... não vejo MUITO o que falar.... mas OK, vou tentar dar uma melhor elucidada a respeito do assunto

Comment: @bigown concordo, mas concordo também com o Marcelo, pois na verdade a pergunta me parece de certa forma incompleta, ou demasiadamente abrangente, e querendo ou não, certas informações são mais facilmente obtidas pesquisando do que aguardar uma resposta pronta, ainda mais sem nenhum fim(ao menos mencionado na pergunta).

Comment: Se não tem o que falar, não fale. Isto não é um fórum. Respostas devem conter conhecimento relevante. Se a pergunta está ruim é outro problema. Se começarmos dizer para os usuários procurarem na internet descaracteriza completamente o objetivo deste *site*.