# Javascript: por que a eval("023") retorna 19?

Tags: javascript, return, eval

Sei que a função não deve ser usada indiscriminadamente, pois possui várias implicações de segurança, conforma pode ser visto aqui:

[Eval é mocinho ou bandido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128845/eval-%C3%A9-mocinho-ou-bandido)

Mas eu estava fazendo um calculadora simples, onde o texto do input, após tratado, é passado para a função eval e retorna o resultado. Porém, ao inserir 023 e pressionar igual (equivalente a passar a string no input para a função eval) me surpreendi com o resultado 19.

Abri o console do Chrome e digitei o código:

```
eval("023")
```

E obtive o seguinte resultado:

```
19
```

Por que o resultado da execução da linha acima é 19?

[image: Veja o código em execução]

Comment: Relacionada: [O que são números de notação Decimal, Hexadecimal e Octal?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47854/91)

Comment: Mas em octal 023 é igual a 27 e em hexadecimal é igual a 17. Não sei se é este o caso...

Comment: 19 octal é igual a 23 decimal :)

Comment: `023 = 2*8 + 3 = 19`. A base octal é indicada por um `0` antes do número, e hexadecimal é `0x`

Comment: Tudo bem galera, vacilo meu aqui. Não notei que o parser do Eval estava interpretando em octal e retornando em decimal, havia entendido o contrário. Valew o help @marceloboni e demais q comentaram.

Comment: Não, você ainda não entendeu, ele lê o decimal `23` e como tem o `0` na frente, ele interpreta o valor decimal como octal, no caso `19`

Comment: @MarceloBoni eu entendi sim, você que não entendeu bem o que eu falei. O retorno é em decimal, visto que não existe dígito 9 em octal.

Comment: @JoséOlinda, veja meu comentário e veja também o link do @rray. Se é um número que começar com `0x`, então é hexadecial, se começa com `0` então é octal, e só no caso contrário ele é considerado decimal. Também vale lembrar que a representação padrão/representação de impressão de um número é como decimal.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado já observei sim, obrigado pelas dicas. Houve um espanto de início com o retorno e não percebi, mas agora está tudo claro. Obrigado por participar.