# Operações onde o valor do dividendo inicia com 0

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$value = 040;
echo $value / 2;
```

Saída:

```
16
```

A variável `$value`e recebe `040` em vez de simplesmente `40`. No entanto, em algumas linguagens, talvez a maioria, o `0` seria desconsiderado, no PHP não.

Qual seria a lógica por trás desta operação?

Comment: O zero representa "octal"

Comment: Relacionada: [O que são números de notação Decimal, Hexadecimal e Octal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47854/91)