# Converter Binário fracionário"flutuante" para Decimal

Tags: c

Então galera alguém aqui sabe como eu faço para converter 
1,01010101 para base 10 no caso esta em base 2 "binaria" a resposta é essa em base10 1.3320312510
. 
Preciso da logica para tratar esse caso ..

att

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int c[18],bcd[20];


//Função de conversão de decimal para binário

void conv_d2b ( unsigned long x,int *c)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<18; i++)
        *(c++)=(x>>i)&0x1;
}





int main()
{
    int escolha;
    double bina ,deci ;
    int k;
    unsigned long int j,x;
    int pos, decimal=0;
    char numb[17];
    int cont=0;

    printf("Conversor de numeros binarios e decimais \n\n");
    printf(" ----------Menu----------\n 1 - Binario para decimal\n 2 - Decimal para binario\n 3 - Decimal fracionario para binario\n 4 - Binario'flutuante' fracionario para Decimal\n 5 - Exit\n\n Opcao: ");
    scanf("%d", &escolha);

    switch(escolha)
    {
    case 1:
        //Conversão de BInarios para Decimal


        printf("Digite um numero Binario qualquer");
        scanf("%s",numb);
        //Processamento da informação
        for (pos=strlen(numb) -1; pos >=0; pos--)
            decimal=decimal + (numb[cont++] - '0')*pow(2,pos);
        //Exibindo a informação
        printf("Seu numero Binario em Decimal eh: %d\n\n", decimal);


        break;

    case 2:


        printf("Digite o numero que deseja converter :");
        scanf("%lu",&x);
        printf("\n\n       \t  Decimal\t      Binario\n");




        printf("   ----  %lu\t    ", x);

        conv_d2b(x,c);
        for(k=17; k>=0; k--)
            printf("%d",c[k]);
        printf("\n\n\r");
        break;

    case 3:

        break;
    case 4:

        break;
    case 5:
        exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Opcao invalida");
        break;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

fiz algo assim

```
int main()
{
    int  inteiro, binarioInt = 0, i = 1;
    float  binarioFrac = 0, k =0.1f, frac, temp1, binarioTotal, f;

    printf("***** Converter valor FLOAT para BINARIO *******\n");
     printf("***** POR FAVOR UTILIZE PONTO PARA SEPARAR OS NUMEROS *******\n");
    printf("\nEnter com o valor : ");
    scanf("%f",&f);

    //Separando parte inteira
    inteiro = (int)f;

    //Separanto parte fracionada
    frac = f - (int)f;

    //Loop para converter decimal parte inteira em binario
    while(inteiro>0)
    {
        binarioInt = binarioInt + inteiro % 2 * i;
        i = i * 10;
        inteiro = inteiro / 2;
    }

    //Loop para converter fracao em binario
    while(k>0.00000001)
    {
        temp1 = frac *2;
        binarioFrac = binarioFrac+((int)temp1)*k;
        frac = temp1 - (int)temp1;
        k = k / 10;
    }

        //
        binarioTotal = binarioInt +binarioFrac;
        printf(" \nbinary equivalent = %lf\n\n\n\n\n", binarioTotal);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desculpa a demora para postar a resposta ..
Caso alguém consiga de outras formas só enviar, seria de ajuda para muitos. 
No caso o programa ai também converte decimal float para binário,
binario float para decimal...

```
/*Trabalho de Calculo numerico  - Converter numero binario para numero decimal*/





#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
#define max 30

int fraci[max],inteiro[max];

//Funcoes
void decimalparabinario();
void binarioparadecimal();
float pow();
//Fim Funcoes



int main()
{
    int op;
    float aux,num,f;
    int i,cnum,ch;
    do
    {
        printf("===== Menu ======\n");
        printf("1. Binario para Decimal\n");
        printf("2. Decimal para Binario\n");
        printf("3. Sair\n");
        printf("Digite uma opcao: \n");
        scanf("%d",&op); //
        system("clear"); //Comando utilizado para limpar tela


        switch(op)
        {
        case 1:

            binarioparadecimal();
            system("PAUSE");


            break;
        case 2:
            decimalparabinario();

            system("PAUSE");


            break;
        case 3://Sair do programa
            printf("Saindo..\n");

            break;
        default://Caso não seja nenhuma das anteriores...
            printf("Opcao Invalida\n");
            break;



        }



    }
    while(op != 3);


    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

void decimalparabinario(){

    float numero,f;
    int i,cnum,t;

    printf("Digite um numero Decimal  : ");
    scanf("%f",&numero);
    printf("\n");

    f=numero-(int)numero;

    for(i=0; i<max; i++)
    {
        f=f-(int)f;
        fraci[i]=(int)(f*2);
        f*=2;
    }

    cnum=(int)numero;
    for(i=max-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if(cnum%2==0)
        {
            inteiro[i]=0;
        }
        else
            inteiro[i]=1;
        cnum/=2;
    }

    printf("O numero em Binario é igual   = ");
    t=0;

    for(i=0; i<max; i++)
    {
        if(inteiro[i]||t)
        {
            t=1;
            printf("%d",inteiro[i]);
        }
    }
    printf(".");

    for(i=0; i<7; i++)
        printf("%d",fraci[i]);

    printf("\n");



}


void binarioparadecimal()
{
    char num[50];
    int antesDec[50], depoisDec[50];
    int antesDecnum, depoisDecnum, tint=0, l, j=0, k=0;
    float fract=0, floatValue;
    char p = 'd';

    printf("******* Insira o binario para converter  para decimal *********\n");

    //
    printf("Digite o numero binario : ");
    scanf("%s",&num);

    //Separa o inteiro do fracionado

    for(l=0; l<strlen(num); l++)
    {
        if(num[l]=='.')
        {
            p='u';
        }
        else if(p=='d')
        {

            antesDec[l] = (int)num[l]-48;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            depoisDec[j] = (int)num[l]-48;
            j++;
        }
    }

    // Armazena o tamanho do inteiro e do fracionario
    antesDecnum = k;
    depoisDecnum= j;

    //Converter parte inteira para decimal
    j=0;
    for(l = antesDecnum-1; l>=0; l--)
    {
        tint = tint + (antesDec[l] *(int) pow(2,j));
        j++;
    }

    //Converter parte fracionaria para decimal
    j = -1;
    for(l = 0; l<depoisDecnum; l++)
    {
        fract = fract + (depoisDec[l]*pow(2,j));
        j--;
    }

    //Juntando as duas partes
    floatValue = tint + fract;
    printf("Numero em decimal é  = %f\n\n\n\n\n",floatValue);


}
float pow(int c, int d)
{
    float pow=1;
    if (d >= 0)
    {
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= d)
        {
            pow = pow * c;
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i > d)
        {
            pow = pow/c;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return pow;
}


// intnum = numero inteiro.
// fracnume = numero fracionario
```

Comment: Sempre que possível é preferível usar `double` para números de vírgula flutuante. Todas as operações com `float` convertem primeiro esse valor no tipo `double`, por exemplo: `float x = 4.2; x *= 2; /* operação feita em double */`. Além disto os processadores aritméticos actuais estão optimizados para o tipo `double` fazendo com que operações com tipos `float` sejam mais lentas embora o número de bits usado seja menor.

Comment: Ótima dica, vou usar nos proximos!!!

Answer (score 6):

Isso é fácil de se resolver com matemática básica:

```
1.01010101
```

é o mesmo que

```
101010101 / 100000000
```

(basta contar as casas depois da vírgula)

```
 Binário       Decimal
 101010101 ÷   314 ÷
 100000000     256
────────────  ─────────────
 1.01010101    1.332031251
```

Em resumo, basta converter normalmente, e trabalhar em decimal.

Para simplificar, conte as casas depois da vírgula, faça `2 ^ Número de casas`<sup>1</sup> e use como divisor:

```
1.01010101
  └───┬──┘
      └── 8 casas

101010101 = 314
    2 ^ 8 = 256
    │   └───────── 8 casas
    └───────────── base 2, binário. Se fosse decimal, seria 10, hexadecimal 16 etc.

314/256 = 1.332031251
```

<sub>1. Estou usando `a ^ b` para indicar `a` elevado a `b`.</sub>

### E se fosse hexadecimal?

Mesma coisa:

```
  F,1BC
    └┬┘
     └── 3 casas

  F1BC = 61884
16 ^ 3 =  4096
 │   └───────── 3 casas
 └───────────── base 16

61884/4096 = 15,1083984375
```

**Nota:** eu vi a outra pergunta aqui no site sobre mostrar número com casas decimais em binário. Acho que fica muito mais simples usar esta mesma técnica aqui naquele caso também:

Vá multiplicando o número por 2, até não ter mais decimais. Anote quantas vezes multiplicou. O número de vezes é a posição da vírgula no binário. (se quiser adiantar esta etapa, dá pra deduzir com logaritmo, mas como está fora da pergunta atual, não vou entrar em detalhes).

Uma coisa que eu já mencionei em [outra questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13573/) e se aplica neste caso: independente da base que você trabalha, [a matemática é a mesma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13573/).

Answer (score 0):

Fugindo um pouco da teoria e indo direto a pratica.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int bin2des(unsigned long long bin){
    int x;
    int y;
    char num[18];
    sprintf(num,"%d",bin);
    x = strlen(num);
    y = 1;
    int res;

    while(x--){
        if(num[x] == '-')
            res *= -1;
        else
            res += (num[x]-48)*y;
        y *= 2;
    }

    return res;
}

void main(){
    printf("%i\n",bin2des(101));
}
```

Comment: Eu consegui fazer aqui depois eu envio o código pra caso alguém queira !!!

Comment: @MatheusFrancisco mesmo a pergunta sendo sua, você pode postar sua solução no espaço para respostas. É uma prática normal, e também é uma maneira de ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema.