# Como fazer estrutura de decisão para mudar cor em um bat?

Tags: windows, batch, prompt, ping

Olá, gostaria de saber como fazer uma tomada de decisão na seguinte situação:
Tenho uma janela do cmd com um ping constante, queria que o script analisasse quando o ping estivesse normal as letras do cmd ficassem na cor verde, se caso ficasse sem conexão alteraria para vermelho...

Comment: Acredito que não seja possível, quando você "invoca" uma aplicação, o script só vai ter o "poder" de fazer alguma coisa, após essa aplicação encerrar.

Comment: em princípio teria que fazer um loop, e pings individuais dentro do loop.

Comment: e provavelmente usar um programa auxiliar pra mudar a cor individualmente. o COLOR muda da tela toda.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Importante notar que para mudar a cor individualmente por linha, você precisa de algum programa auxiliar.

O resto é basicamente isso:

```
//salvar como cping.bat ou coisa do tipo
//uso: cping <IP>

@ECHO off
:top
PING -n 1 %1% | find "%1%"
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO yes
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO no
:yes
COLOR 2
ECHO Ping OK
GOTO top
:no
COLOR 4
ECHO Ping FAIL
GOTO top
```

Note que no caso, a cor da janela inteira muda, para fazer linhas individuais de cores diferentes, é necessário trocar o `COLOR` por algum utilitário externo.

Obviamente é apenas um esboço, mas já tem a lógica completa para você adaptar conforme achar necessário.

A linha `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO yes` foi mais para mostrar a sintaxe, na verdade o `GOTO no` teoricamente deve bastar.

A sintaxe do comando é:

```
COLOR <cor de fundo + cor da letra em hexadecimal>
```

As cores disponiveis em hexadecimal:

```
0 preto         8 cinza escuro (seria o "preto claro" kkk)
1 azul          9 azul claro
2 verde         a verde claro
3 ciano         b ciano claro
4 vermelho      c vermelho claro
5 magenta       d magenta claro
6 amarelo       e amarelo claro
7 cinza         f branco
```

Em outras palavras, cada nibble (meio byte) tem 4 bits, nesta ordem: [I~] Intensidade, [R] Vermelho, [G] Verde, [B] Azul:

```
IRGB -> binário 1011 -> hexadecimal "e" -> Amarelo claro
```

Efetivamente gerando um valor neste formato

```
I R G B  I R G B
^fundo^ ^frente^
```

Exemplo para alterar as letras para amarelo forte e fundo verde escuro:

```
color 2e
```

(`2e` em hexadecimal é `00101110`, ou seja fundo G + frente IRG )

Leitura complementar:

> [Como funcionam os números em hexadecimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13573/70)

### Colorindo as linhas da saída individualmente

Aqui tem um utilitário que faz `ECHO` colorido:

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17033/Add-Colors-to-Batch-Files

Segue o código adaptado para linhas coloridas separadamente, usando o utilitário mencionado:

```
@ECHO off

:top
CECHO {08}
PING -n 1 %1% | find "%1%"

IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO yes
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO no

:yes
CECHO {0A}Ping OK
GOTO top

:no
CECHO {0C}:Ping FAIL
GOTO top
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou certinho.

Answer (score 1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Algo assim?**

```
    @echo off && setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

(

if exist "%temp%\bg.b64" del /q /f "%temp%\bg.b64"
if exist "%temp%\bg.exe" del /q /f "%temp%\bg.exe"

) >nul 2>&1 

echo/ & echo/  && call :_base64_to_exe && Certutil.exe -decode "%temp%\bg.b64" "%temp%\bg.exe" >nul 2>&1

if exist "%temp%\bg.exe" ( 

     set _bg="%temp%\bg.exe"

     for %%I in (8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2) do (

         for /f "tokens=4 delims=^=" %%i in ('ping -n 1 %%I ^| findstr /i /c:"ms"') do (

             !_bg! print \n && set "_ms=%%~i"&& set /a _ms=!_ms:ms=!

            )

             if  "!_ms!" geq "0" (

                 !_bg! print f " Host" b " online" a " %%I" c ":" e  " !_ms!" a "ms"

                 echo/ & echo/ 

                 set _ms=

                ) else ( 

                 echo/ & echo/ 

                 !_bg! print f " Host" c " offline" b ":" a " %%I"

                 echo/ & echo/ <nul

                ) 

        )

      ) else ( 

       color c && echo/E R R O R: "%temp%\bg.exe" not found...

       2>nul >nul (del /q /f "%temp%\bg64" &  "%temp%\bg.exe" del /q /f "%temp%\bg.exe")

       goto :_end_of_file

      )

:_base64_to_exe

(echo/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
echo/TVqQAAMAAAAEAAAA//8AALgAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAA4fug4AtAnNIbgBTM0hVGhpcyBwcm9ncmFtIGNhbm5v
echo/dCBiZSBydW4gaW4gRE9TIG1vZGUuDQ0KJAAAAAAAAABQRQAATAECAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOAADwMLAQYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA1x0AAAAQAAAAIAAAAABAAAAQAAAAAgAA
echo/BAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAwAAAAAgAA5xUBAAMAAAAAABAAABAAAAAAEAAAEAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHAgAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
echo/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADUIAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC50ZXh0AAAA
echo/KA8AAAAQAAAAEAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAGAuZGF0YQAAAJAEAAAAIAAAAAQAAAASAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
echo/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABVieWB7AAAAACQuAMAAACLDYAkQAA5yA+FGwAAAIsFhCRAAIPACIsIiQ3EI0AA6OoJAADp4wAAALgEAAAAiw2A
echo/JEAAOcgPj9AAAAC4AgAAAIkFACRAAIsFgCRAAEiJBQQkQAC46CNAAFCLBeAjQABQ6NsNAACLBQAkQACLDQQkQAA5yA+NfgAAAIsFACRAAInBQIkFACRAAMHhAosFhCRA
echo/AAHIuRAAAABRuQAAAABRiwhR6KENAACDxAyB4P//AABmiQXAI0AAiwUAJEAAicFAiQUAJEAAweECiwWEJEAAAciLCIkNxCNAAA+3BcAjQABQiwXgI0AAUOhjDQAA6BsJ
echo/AADpbv///w+3BfAjQABQiwXgI0AAUOhFDQAAycNVieWB7AAAAACQuAQAAACLDYAkQAA5yA+PSAEAALgEAAAAiQUIJEAAiwWAJEAASIkFDCRAALjoI0AAUIsF4CNAAFDo
echo/7AwAALh/HEAAiQUAIEAAiwWEJEAAg8AMuQoAAABRuQAAAABRiwhR6MwMAACDxAzB4BDB+BBmiQXWI0AAiwWEJEAAg8AIuQoAAABRuQAAAABRiwhR6J8MAACDxAzB4BDB
echo/+BBmiQXYI0AAD78F1iNAAGaJBcgjQAC4AQAAAGaJBc4jQAC4AQAAAGaJBdAjQAC4AAAAAGaJBdIjQAC4AAAAAGaJBdQjQACLBQgkQACLDQwkQAA5yA+NZwAAAIsFCCRA
echo/AInBQIkFCCRAAMHhAosFhCRAAAHIuRAAAABRuQAAAABRiwhR6A8MAACDxAyB4P//AABmiQXMI0AAiwUIJEAAicFAiQUIJEAAweECiwWEJEAAAciLCIkNxCNAAOidBwAA
echo/64XJw1WJ5YHsAAAAAJC4BAAAAIsNgCRAADnID4WDAAAAiwWEJEAAg8AMuQoAAABRuQAAAABRiwhR6JoLAACDxAzB4BDB+BBmiQUQJEAAiwWEJEAAg8AIuQoAAABRuQAA
echo/AABRiwhR6G0LAACDxAzB4BDB+BBmiQUSJEAAgewEAAAAieC5BAAAAFG5ECRAAFFQ6FMLAACDxAyLBeAjQABQ6EwLAADJw1WJ5YHsAAAAAJDoQwsAAIXAD4QFAAAA6AIA
echo/AADJw1WJ5YHsAAAAAJDoLQsAAIkFbCBAAIsFbCBAAIXAD4QYAAAAuOAAAACLDWwgQAA5yA+EBQAAAOkRAAAA6PwKAACBwP8AAACJBWwgQADJw1WJ5YHsAAAAAJC49v//
echo//1Do4QoAAIkF5CNAALgUJEAAUIsF5CNAAFDo0QoAAIsFFCRAAIPIEIPgv4Pg/okFGCRAAIsFGCRAAFCLBeQjQABQ6LEKAAC4HCRAAFC4AQAAAFC4ICRAAFCLBeQjQABQ
echo/6JsKAAC4AgAAAA+3DSAkQAA5yA+FQgAAAIsFKCRAAIkFNCRAALgBAAAAiw00JEAAOcgPhSMAAAAPvwUkJEAAUA+/BSYkQABQuAQgQABQ6FUKAACDxAzpAgAAAOuKiwUU
echo/JEAAUIsF5CNAAFDoKAoAAMnDVYnlgewAAAAAkLg4JEAAUOgpCgAAD7cFRiRAAFAPtwVEJEAAUA+3BUIkQABQD7cFQCRAAFAPtwU8JEAAUA+3BT4kQABQD7cFOiRAAFAP
echo/twU4JEAAULgKIEAAUOjWCQAAg8QkycNVieWB7AAAAACQuAMAAACLDYAkQAA5yA+FJgAAAIsFhCRAAIPACLkKAAAAUbkAAAAAUYsIUehHCQAAg8QMUOieCQAAycNVieWB
echo/7AAAAACQuAMAAACLDYAkQAA5yA+F1wAAALhIJEAAUIsF4CNAAFDodQkAAIsFhCRAAIPACLkKAAAAUbkAAAAAUYsIUejwCAAAg8QMiQVQJEAAiwVQJEAA6QUAAADpCQAA
echo/AIP4AA+FFQAAALgAAAAAiQVMJEAA6WQAAADpCQAAAIP4AQ+FFQAAALgBAAAAiQVMJEAA6UYAAADpCQAAAIP4GQ+FBQAAAOkJAAAAg/gyD4UFAAAA6QkAAACD+GQPhRwA
echo/AAC4AQAAAIkFTCRAAIsFUCRAAIkFSCRAAOkAAAAAuEgkQABQiwXgI0AAUOi4CAAAycNVieWB7AAAAACQuAMAAACLDYAkQAA5yA+FMwAAAIsFhCRAAIPACLkKAAAAUbkA
echo/AAAAUYsIUegMCAAAg8QMgeD/AAAAUIsF4CNAAFDobggAAMnDVYnlgewAAAAAkLgDAAAAiw2AJEAAOcgPj6YAAAC4AQAAAIkFVCRAALgSAAIAiQVYJEAAuAQAAACLDYAk
echo/QAA5yA+PQAAAAIsFhCRAAIPADLkKAAAAUbkAAAAAUYsIUeiRBwAAg8QMiQVUJEAAiwVUJEAAg/gAD40LAAAAuAAAAACJBVQkQACLBVQkQACFwA+ELwAAAIsFhCRAAIPA
echo/CIsNWCRAAFG5AAAAAFGLCFHowgcAAIsFVCRAAIPA/4kFVCRAAOvDycNVieWB7AAAAACQuAEAAACLDYAkQAA5yA+N1QIAAIsFhCRAAIPABIsIiQ1gJEAAiwVgJEAAiQVk
echo/JEAAiwVkJEAAD74IhckPhB0AAACLBWQkQAAPvgiD4V+ICIsFZCRAAECJBWQkQADr0rgiIEAAUIsFYCRAAFDoPQcAAIPECIXAD4QFAAAA6RAAAAC4ABBAAIkFXCRAAOkx
echo/AgAAuCggQABQiwVgJEAAUOgLBwAAg8QIhcAPhAUAAADpEAAAALgdEUAAiQVcJEAA6f8BAAC4LyBAAFCLBWAkQABQ6NkGAACDxAiFwA+EBQAAAOkQAAAAuIQSQACJBVwk
echo/QADpzQEAALg2IEAAUIsFYCRAAFDopwYAAIPECIXAD4QFAAAA6RAAAAC4JhNAAIkFXCRAAOmbAQAAuDsgQABQiwVgJEAAUOh1BgAAg8QIhcAPhAUAAADpEAAAALhEE0AA
echo/iQVcJEAA6WkBAAC4PyBAAFCLBWAkQABQ6EMGAACDxAiFwA+EBQAAAOkQAAAAuJITQACJBVwkQADpNwEAALhFIEAAUIsFYCRAAFDoEQYAAIPECIXAD4QFAAAA6RAAAAC4
echo/chRAAIkFXCRAAOkFAQAAuEogQABQiwVgJEAAUOjfBQAAg8QIhcAPhAUAAADpEAAAALjXFEAAiQVcJEAA6dMAAAC4UCBAAFCLBWAkQABQ6K0FAACDxAiFwA+EBQAAAOkQ
echo/AAAAuBwVQACJBVwkQADpoQAAALhXIEAAUIsFYCRAAFDoewUAAIPECIXAD4QFAAAA6RAAAAC4EhZAAIkFXCRAAOlvAAAAuFwgQABQiwVgJEAAUOhJBQAAg8QIhcAPhAUA
echo/AADpEAAAALhkFkAAiQVcJEAA6T0AAAC4YSBAAFCLBWAkQABQ6BcFAACDxAiFwA+EBQAAAOkQAAAAuJsdQACJBVwkQADpCwAAALgAAAAAiQVcJEAAiwVcJEAAhcAPhBkA
echo/AAC49f///1DoewQAAIkF4CNAAIsFXCRAAP/QycNVieWB7AAAAACQuAAAAACJBWgkQAC4AAAAAIkFbCRAALgAAAAAiQVwJEAAiwXEI0AAiQV4JEAAiwV4JEAAD74IiQ10
echo/JEAAhckPhPIBAACLBXAkQACFwA+EBQAAAOk/AAAAuFwAAACLDXQkQAA5yLgAAAAAD5TAiQVwJEAAhcAPhAUAAADpEgAAAIsFdCRAAFCLBQAgQAD/0IPEBOmOAQAAiwV0
echo/JEAAUOgfBAAAg8QEhcAPhLYAAACLBWwkQACD+AIPjWcAAACLBWwkQABAiQVsJEAAiwVoJEAAweAEiQVoJEAAiwV0JEAAg/g5uAAAAAAPnsCFwA+EDgAAAIsFdCRAAIPo
echo/MOkRAAAAiwV0JEAAg8ggg+hX6QAAAACLDWgkQAABwYkNaCRAAOk7AAAAiwVoJEAAUIsFACBAAP/Qg8QEiwV0JEAAUIsFACBAAP/Qg8QEuAAAAACJBWgkQACJBWwkQACJ
echo/BXAkQADpwQAAAIsFbCRAAIXAD4RiAAAAiwVoJEAAUIsFACBAAP/Qg8QEuFwAAACLDXQkQAA5yLgAAAAAD5TAiQVwJEAAhcAPhAUAAADpEgAAAIsFdCRAAFCLBQAgQAD/
echo/0IPEBLgAAAAAiQVoJEAAiQVsJEAA6VEAAACLBXQkQADpBQAAAOkJAAAAg/huD4UWAAAAuAoAAABQiwUAIEAA/9CDxATpFwAAAIsFdCRAAFCLBQAgQAD/0IPEBOkAAAAA
echo/uAAAAACJBXAkQACLBXgkQABAiQV4JEAA6ff9//+LBWwkQACFwA+EEgAAAIsFaCRAAFCLBQAgQAD/0IPEBMnDVYnlgewAAAAAkItFCOkFAAAA6QkAAACD+AAPhRkAAAAP
echo/vwXWI0AAQGaJBdYjQADp3gAAAOkJAAAAg/gKD4UiAAAAD78F2CNAAEBmiQXYI0AAD78FyCNAAGaJBdYjQADprgAAAA+/BdYjQACD+AAPjIoAAAAPvwXYI0AAg/gAD4x6
echo/AAAAD75FCIgFyiNAAA+/BdYjQABAZokF2iNAAA+/BdgjQABAZokF3CNAALjWI0AAUIHsBAAAAInguQQAAABRudIjQABRUOgdAQAAg8QMgewEAAAAieC5BAAAAFG5ziNA
echo/AFFQ6AABAACDxAy4yiNAAFCLBeAjQABQ6HMBAAAPvwXWI0AAQGaJBdYjQADpAAAAAItFCOkAAAAAycNVieWB7AAAAACQ6E4BAACJBXwkQAC4AAAAAIsNfCRAADnID4QS
echo/AAAAuAMAAABQiwV8JEAAUOgrAQAAycNVieWB7AQAAACQuAAAAACJRfyNRfxQuAAAAABQuIgkQABQuIQkQABQuIAkQABQ6P4AAACDxBTo/gAAAIkFjCRAALjkBAAAUOj1
echo/AAAA6AH5//+LBYwkQABQ6OQAAACLBWwgQABQ6OAAAACDxATJwwAAAP8l1CBAAAAA/yUAIUAAAAD/JdggQAAAAP8lBCFAAAAA/yXcIEAAAAD/JQghQAAAAP8l4CBAAAAA
echo//yXkIEAAAAD/JQwhQAAAAP8lECFAAAAA/yUUIUAAAAD/JRghQAAAAP8l6CBAAAAA/yUcIUAAAAD/JSAhQAAAAP8lJCFAAAAA/yUoIUAAAAD/JSwhQAAAAP8lRCFAAAAA
echo//yXsIEAAAAD/JfAgQAAAAP8lMCFAAAAA/yU0IUAAAAD/JUwhQAAAAP8l9CBAAAAA/yU4IUAAAAD/JTwhQAAAAP8l+CBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
echo/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
echo/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
echo/SB5AACVkICVkACVkICVkICVkICVkICVkICVkICVkICVkAFBSSU5UAFNQUklURQBMT0NBVEUAX0tCRABLQkQATU9VU0UAVElNRQBTTEVFUABDVVJTT1IARk9OVABQTEFZ
echo/AE1BWElNSVpFAAAAAAAAAFQhAAAAAAAAAAAAANQhAADUIAAAgCEAAAAAAAAAAAAAQiIAAAAhAADEIQAAAAAAAAAAAACPIwAARCEAAMwhAAAAAAAAAAAAAKYjAABMIQAA
echo/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADfIQAA6SEAAPMhAAD8IQAABSIAAA4iAAAXIgAAICIAACsiAAA7IgAAAAAAAE8iAABsIgAAhiIAAKEiAACwIgAAwSIAANIiAADmIgAA
echo/9SIAAP0iAAAUIwAAKyMAADwjAABSIwAAZSMAAHojAAAAAAAAmSMAAAAAAACxIwAAAAAAAN8hAADpIQAA8yEAAPwhAAAFIgAADiIAABciAAAgIgAAKyIAADsiAAAAAAAA
echo/TyIAAGwiAACGIgAAoSIAALAiAADBIgAA0iIAAOYiAAD1IgAA/SIAABQjAAArIwAAPCMAAFIjAABlIwAAeiMAAAAAAACZIwAAAAAAALEjAAAAAAAAbXN2Y3J0LmRsbAAA
echo/AHB1dGNoYXIAAABzdHJ0b3VsAAAAbWVtY3B5AAAAX2tiaGl0AAAAX2dldGNoAAAAcHJpbnRmAAAAc3RyY21wAAAAaXN4ZGlnaXQAAABfX2dldG1haW5hcmdzAAAAZXhp
echo/dABrZXJuZWwzMi5kbGwAAABHZXRDb25zb2xlU2NyZWVuQnVmZmVySW5mbwAAAFNldENvbnNvbGVUZXh0QXR0cmlidXRlAAAAU2V0Q29uc29sZUN1cnNvclBvc2l0aW9u
echo/AAAAR2V0U3RkSGFuZGxlAAAAR2V0Q29uc29sZU1vZGUAAABTZXRDb25zb2xlTW9kZQAAAFJlYWRDb25zb2xlSW5wdXRBAAAAR2V0TG9jYWxUaW1lAAAAU2xlZXAAAABH
echo/ZXRDb25zb2xlQ3Vyc29ySW5mbwAAAFNldENvbnNvbGVDdXJzb3JJbmZvAAAAU2V0Q29uc29sZUZvbnQAAABXcml0ZUNvbnNvbGVPdXRwdXRBAAAAR2V0Q29uc29sZVdp
echo/bmRvdwAAAEdldENvbnNvbGVPdXRwdXRDUAAAAFNldENvbnNvbGVPdXRwdXRDUAB3aW5tbS5kbGwAAABQbGF5U291bmRBAHVzZXIzMi5kbGwAAABTaG93V2luZG93AAAA
echo/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
echo/-----END CERTIFICATE-----)>>"%temp%\bg.b64" && exit /b || echo/ Base64 to exe unsuccessful...

:_end_of_file

2>nul >nul  del /q /f !_bg!
```