# Não ha controlador ANSI no windows 7, qual é um substituto?

Tags: c, windows-7

Para formatação simples em `C`, pode ser usado controlador `ANSI` do DOS, que tinha nos micros da IBM e no Windows XP, porém o windows 7 não tem suporte para o controlador `ANSI`.
Há um substituto com tais funções?

Comment: Quais funções? Posicionamento? Cores? Seria legal detalhar um pouco na pergunta.

Comment: Nunca consegui fazer funcionar no windows7, nem para cor e nem para posicionamento, no Windows10 testei estes dias e parece ter suporte nativo.

Comment: @ederwander pra cor esses tempos atrás eu postei uma alternativa (mas com comando externo) http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123801/70. Posicionamento eu só usei em Harbour, mas aí já é função nativa.

Comment: Talvez o AnsiCon seja a solução: https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon

Comment: eeu me refiro a mundança de cor e posicionamento do texto. Como sou pouco conhecedor de programação, o que é função nativa??