# Como converter NFA para datatime e vice-versa?

Tags: php

Tendo uma data (ex: 2017-01-18 11:08:09 (formato Y-m-d H:i:s)), o NFA gerado resulta em A70171480.

Pesquisando sobre, pouco encontrei, ainda mais em português. Pra ser sincero, ainda não vi motivos suficientes para usa-lo (até agora entendo como complicação, mas pode ser simples e eu estar enganado).

Existe um [site que realiza a conversão](http://54.207.0.45/nfa/).

Como chegar a este resultado?

E o oposto? tendo X NFA, como converte-lo para datatime?

O NFA segue algum padrão?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Este formato que você colocou na pergunta guarda a hora nos últimos cinco dígitos hexadecimais, e o restante é a data (ambos com um fator de ajuste).

Você pode fazer uma conversão de NFA para *timestamp* com esta fórmula:

```
function nfaToTs($nfa) { 
   $nfadata = hexdec(substr($nfa,0,-5));
   $nfahora = hexdec(substr($nfa,-5));
   return ($nfadata-25569) * 86400 + ($nfahora - 7) / 11.574;
}
```

Modo de usar:

```
$timestamp = nfaToTs('A70171480');

// Formate como quiser depois:
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/lyQi5g)**.

De *timestamp* para NFA, é mera inversão da lógica:

```
function tsToNfa($ts) {
   $hexdata = substr('0000' .dechex($ts / 86400 + 25569 ), -4);
   $hexhora = substr('00000'.dechex($ts % 86400 * 11.574 + 7), -5);
   return $hexdata.$hexhora;
}
```

Modo de usar:

```
// qualquer coisa que retorne um timestamp
$ts = strtotime('1980-01-31 15:53:09 GMT'); 

echo tsToNfa($ts);
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/lyQi5g)**.

Curiosidades:

- O número de dias entre o *posix timestamp* e o primeiro dia do ano de 1900 é `25567`, talvez a constante `25569` guarde alguma relação com este ajuste de 70 anos;
- em hexa, o decimal `1.000.000` é `0xF4240`, que é o horário limite do NFA;
- um dia tem `86400` segundos, e ao dividirmos `1.000.000` por `86.400` o resultado *por acaso* é `11.574`;

Leitura complementar:

> [Como funcionam os números em hexadecimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13573/70)

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.hexdec.php